# why is using 'which()' function faster?

Tags: r, subset

```
testdata = round(matrix(runif(1e5),5000,20),1)

system.time({
for (i in 1:1e5) {
   test1 = testdata[which(testdata[,1] == 0.5),]
}
})

system.time({
for (i in 1:1e5) {
    test2 = testdata[testdata[,1]==0.5]
  }
})
```

When I run the above code, the former takes about 5.0 seconds while the latter takes about 5.9 seconds.
(In another situation, the former took only one third of time of the latter.)

Why does subsetting by `which()` command take less time than the other?

Comment: This comparison is unfair. the second one is subseting elements of the matrix while the first one is subsetting rows. If you try `test2 = testdata[testdata[,1]==0.5,]`, the speed is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're not subsetting with the same type of vector. The one with `which` is a short number index while the second is a vector of TRUE/FALSE.

```
# Vector of index
> length(which(testdata[,1] == 0.5))
[1] 505
# Vector of TRUE/FALSE
> length(testdata[,1]==0.5)
[1] 5000
```

So the first matches the indexed rows, while the second evaluates all the rows.

Best,

Colin